# Angular2 (alpha.55) and SystemJs fails

Tags: angular, systemjs

I don't understand why since I use alpha.55 version of angular2, my project fails to load properly.

Error in my browser:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/angular2/platform/browser.js 404 (Not Found)fetchTextFromURL ...
GET http://localhost:8080/angular2/core.js 404 (Not Found)fetchTextFromURL ...
GET http://localhost:8080/angular2/http.js 404 (Not Found) ....
...
```

In the header of my index.html file

```
<script src="\lib\system.src.js?v=0.1.0"></script>
<script src="\lib\angular2.dev.js?v=0.1.0"></script>
<script src="\lib\http.dev.js?v=0.1.0"></script>
```

And the way I load all the stuff

```
System.config(
        {
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
            map: {
                "bootstrap": "/components/landing/landing.js"
            }
        });
System.import('bootstrap');
```

Then my landing.js file

```
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, View, Type} from 'angular2/core';
blabla...
```

Do you have any idea why systemjs is not using dowloaded bundles (angular and http bundles) anymore ?

Comment: Try putting your angular2.dev and http.dev bundles below your System.config.

Comment: try to make the order of js imports and calls like in this example https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play/blob/master/index.html

Comment: thanx for pointing out important points. could you tell me why we use `<script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>` ?

Comment: @PardeepJain Angular 2 relies on some functionality of the ES6 spec, which browsers don't widely support yet. So until they do, loading this shim lets Angular 2 operate as if that built-in functionality were actually there.